# How to filter multiple fields in a report using comboboxes in a form

Tags: ms-access, report

**The Situation:** I have a report based on a query that I put inside a form.  What I want to do is create 4 comboboxes from which users can choose options that will filter the report without leaving the form or opening the report in a separate window.

Also, I want to make the filters dependent on each other, meaning if I select option A on combobox 1, the options I will select on combobox 2 will only be based on the earlier filter on combobox 1.  I apologize if I'm not explaining this clearly.

**The Issue:** So far I'm able to do at least 2 of the comboboxes to filter the report, but they aren't based on which one was used to filter the report first. So if I filter the records by choosing option A on combobox 1, combobox 2 will still filter every record.

Below is the code used for the two comboboxes:

```vb
Private Sub cboLocation_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

If IsNull(Me.cboLocation) Then
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.Filter = ""
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.FilterOn = False
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.Requery
    Else
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.Filter = "[Location]=" & Me.cboLocation
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.FilterOn = True
    End If

Proc_Exit:
    Exit Sub
Proc_Error:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " in setting subform filter:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Resume Proc_Exit

End Sub
```

==========

```vb
Private Sub cboProduct_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

    If IsNull(Me.cboProduct) Then
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.Filter = ""
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.FilterOn = False
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.Requery

    Else
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.Filter = "[Product]=" & Me.cboProduct
        Me.qrySalesByLocation.Report.FilterOn = True
    End If

Proc_Exit:
    Exit Sub
Proc_Error:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " in setting subform filter:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Resume Proc_Exit

End Sub
```

=====

With the other 2 comboboxes, I can't apply the same code cause the enter parameter dialog keeps popping out.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Once combobox 1 has been used to filter the report.  How will the users ever get to be able to select another combobox instead?   Would they need to close and reopen the form?

Comment: the 4 comboboxes will be available once they open the form. the idea is they can select from among the comboboxes without leaving the form, and the report gets filtered with each selection without also leaving the form.

Comment: The process I want is like this: 

1. I open the form. It displays the report showing all the records. 
2. In the form header, there will be 4 combo boxes that will allow the user to filter the records.
3. Then, after one (or multiple) selections from the combo boxes is (are) made, the report is sorted without leaving the form or opening in a new window. 

Sorry if it's a little convoluted :(